# Laravel return model relationships in JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to return model relationships in JSON, I don't see the relationship fields. That's my query:

```
$customer_subscriptions = CustomerSubscription::has("customer")
                ->has("subscription")
                ->has("federationDiscipline")
                ->where("customer_id", "=", $customer_id)
                ->whereHas("subscription", function($query) use($company_id) {
                    $query->where("company_id", "=", $company_id);
                })
                ->orderBy("start_date", "asc");

        return $customer_subscriptions;
```

That's my result:

```
[0]=>
  array(14) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["customer_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["subscription_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["federation_discipline_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["start_date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-04-01"
    ["end_date"]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-31"
    ["external_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["notes"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_user_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["updated_user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["deleted_user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-06-05 07:28:00"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-06-05 07:28:00"
    ["deleted_at"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

I don't see the subscription's and the customer's relationship field. The result of query should return JSON to AJAX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `->has` only acts as a where condition, it doesn't load that relation in to your result set.

You want to use `->with` instead.

In your case `->with('subscription','federationDiscipline')`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Ok it works. But if I use with, the model could gets also the CustomerSubscription without customer/subscription/federationDiscipline. Can I use with and has both?

Comment: Yes, you can use both.

Answer (score 4):

You have to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationships for them to be included in the json output. You current query only looks if there are relations, it doesn't load them.

For example:

```
$customer_subscriptions = CustomerSubscription::has("customer")
    ->has("subscription")
    ->has("federationDiscipline")
    ->where("customer_id", "=", $customer_id)
    ->whereHas("subscription", function($query) use($company_id) {
        $query->where("company_id", "=", $company_id);
    })
    ->orderBy("start_date", "asc")
    ->with('customer');  // <--- Eager loading the customer

return $customer_subscriptions;

    return $customer_subscriptions;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `with()` method to include relationships in results. For example:

```
$customer_subscriptions = CustomerSubscription::with("customer")->...
```

Alternatively, use the `protected $appends = [...]` attribute on models to force the relationship to be loaded for every query. Keep in mind, however, this will impact queries everywhere the model is used, as it forces the database to query for those relationships every time.

Comment: Ok it works. But if I use with, the model could gets also the CustomerSubscription without customer/subscription/federationDiscipline. Can I use with and has both?

Comment: You certainly can use both, however, I would change the query to `Customer::with("subscription")->...` since you're looking for a specific customer. No need to query the pivot table directly.